# Too many parameters for model creation in controller?

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-orm, kohana-3.2

A have a lot of controllers where I must to save/create new models, it looks like this:

```
public Controller_Test extends Controller_Template {

    if ($post = $this->request->post()) {

        $model = ORM::factory('model');
        $model->param1 = $post['Param1'];
        $model->param2 = $post['Param26'];
        $model->param3 = $post['Param31'];
        $model->param4 = $post['Param13'];
        $model->param5 = $post['Param2'];
        $model->param6 = $post['Param35'];
        $model->param7 = $post['Param10'];
        $model->param8 = $post['Param22'];
        $model->param9 = $post['Param3'];
        $model->save();
    }    

}
```

Is it possible to unify (create a method) thats will save all array?

I know about `$model->values($post)->create();`, but still can't understand how really same it works, as u can see I have different keys of posted parameteres and this might be considered.

In many examples all the data assignemnts take place in controller, but they're really small, in my case I'll suppose to have a huge controllers with a lot of data assignment strings and it will be a bad style coding I think.

Comment: If you can map post keys to fields you can do it less code, but this is not without some risks however. If you automate it, you have to be careful about modifiying protected fields.

Comment: So I am under choice to do a method for example `Create_Model` with params of posted array or leave it as is (though I dont like it).

Comment: Looking at the [API](http://kohanaframework.org/3.0/guide/api/Model#__construct) seems they really leave that at your discretion.  You could leverage PHP magic methods and write generic getters/setters and add a  `populate()` method to your base model, having all other models extend it.  Using `__call` can give you a little more flexibility  when it comes to mapping field results to model properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever you do you need to map the key names in your `$_POST` variable to model property names.

```
$model_post_map = array(
    'param1' => 'Param1',
    'param2' => 'Param26',
    'param3' => 'Param31',
    'param4' => 'Param13',
    'param5' => 'Param2',
    'param6' => 'Param35',
    'param7' => 'Param10',
    'param8' => 'Param22',
    'param9' => 'Param3',
);
$post_model_map = array_flip($model_post_map);

function rekey($arr, $map) {
    $newarr = array();
    foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
        if (isset($map[$k])) {
            $newarr[$map[$k]] = $v;
        }
    }
    return $newarr;
}
$modeldata = rekey($post, $post_model_map);
$model->values($modeldata);
```

You should name your form fields the way you do your models to reduce the impedance mismatch.

You should also use the second argument to `$model->values()` to restrict what a form can change.